# How to check if user is in json file discord

Tags: discord.py

I have my code to print a message if the user is in the json file "Shibaku1.json". Bit confused on how the code would work

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, Shib"])
async def shibaku(ctx, num = ""):
 if num == "all":
    with open('Shibaku0.json') as f:
      users = json.load(f)
      if ctx.author.id in users:
        await ctx.send("test")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```py
@client.command(aliases = ["shib, Shib"])
async def shibaku(ctx, num = ""):
 if num == "all":
    with open('Shibaku0.json') as f:
      users = json.load(f)
      if str(ctx.author.id) in users:
        await ctx.send("test")
```

if works pls consider making answer as accpeted

Comment: no problem :)  , anything else?

Comment: I'll work on some more code and see if I run into any more problems I guess

Comment: should i give my discord user?

Comment: my disc is gim#7326